Error migrations .net
estoy con ASP.net web api y estoy siguiendo un tutorial con identity.
Al hacer dotnet ef migrations add Initial, es como si me eliminase las dependencias que he instalado de ef, sqlserver, identityefcore... y tengo que cerrar el visual studio y vovler a instalarlas con nuget.
Me debería de crear una carpeta de migrations que si no equivoco es como la creacion de la db con el DdContext que he asignado, que al usar un IdentityUser, creará una tabla User con username y pass.
Sabeis que puede ser?
Un saludo.
